# Assigning and manipulating values in a Date array

Tags: vba, excel

So I am trying to use a date array but have come across a lot of trouble with it. i've tried just about everything I can think of but can't get it to work.

Essentially what the problem is, is that I can't get the date(the month in particular) that I insert into the array to be accepted. All of the information is stored in the appropriate variables but it isn't be assigned to the array index.

```
'grabs the date
If k = 0 Then
    intDay = Cells(intRowNum + 2, 2).Value
    arrDateTime(intArrayIndex) = DateValue(strMonth & " " & intDay & ", " & intYear)
ElseIf j = 0 Then
    arrDateTime(intArrayIndex) = DateAdd("d", 1, arrDateTime(intArrayIndex - 1))
ElseIf j = 1 Then
    arrDateTime(intArrayIndex) = arrDateTime(intArrayIndex - 1)
End If
strTemp = "" 'resets temporary variable


'grabs the time
If j = 0 Then
    arrDateTime(intArrayIndex) = arrDateTime(intArrayIndex) + TimeValue(Cells(intRowNum + 3, 1).Value)
Else
    arrDateTime(intArrayIndex) = arrDateTime(intArrayIndex) + TimeValue(Cells(intRowNum + intMaxRows + 3, 1).Value)
End If
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to assign the date/time to a date array?

### Update 1

Turns out the information was being retrieved incorrectly, had to use MonthName(Month(arrDateTime(intArrayIndex))) not just the MonthName. The other month information however was showing which was and still is a mystery. So the above issue for the most part is now solved , however the DateAdd() portion is not working properly.

Also please note that I have simplified the elseif statements to just one else statement

```
arrDateTime(intArrayIndex) = DateAdd("d", j-1, arrDateTime(intArrayIndex - 1))
```

Neither codes worked properly though for the DateAdd portion. I've tested arrDateTime(2) = arrDateTime(1) and worked fine, so apparently there is something wrong with the array indexing as whenever I use it it returns a date that is way off.

Comment: Can't get month to be accepted means what, that you get a type mismatch error?

Comment: It comes out the other side as nothing, there is no information in the place of month when I try to retrieve it.

Comment: Have you tried Dan Cook's or my suggested fixes yet?

Comment: Tried them both, neither of them worked so I went through my code again and did msgbox debugging. Turns out I was recalling the information incorrectly, but 90% of it decided to come out anyways.

Comment: I was in the process of suggesting checking the values of the arguments into DateTime *other* than the month, since I was able to get to work the assignment of the DateTime function result (with string Month) to a Date type array. I don't think the problem is the month, unless that variable is picking up something you are not expecting.

Comment: I just managed to solve the problem a bit ago, as I said in my update I was retrieving the information incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the format for your `strMonth`, but if possible use [DateSerial](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dateserial-function-HA001228813.aspx) instead for example:

```
arrDateTime(intArrayIndex) = DateSerial(intYear, strMonth, intDay)
```

Comment: Tried it, but it doesn't work with the way that the Date variables are formated.

Answer (score 0):

If your month value is in the form of a name ("May"), use a month number instead (e.g., "5").   You can do this using MONTH("1"&strMonth).

Comment: The DateValue function is supposed to take the month in the form of a name. http://www.excel-vba-easy.com/vba-programming-date-time-excel-vba.html

Tried it anyways, didn't work :(